# Starting version 219 after upgrading 15.04

Tags: boot, 15.04, lubuntu

I have Lubuntu installed on a USB stick (normal installation). After upgrading to 15.04 the system boots always in Emergency mode and starting version 219. I can continue by pressing <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd> which lets log on screen to appear. It's not a big issue but I can not resolve it. I tried at least 3 things-

1. Start dmlight services -f (no good result).
2. In fstab there seems nothing to comment out.
3. Upgrade or downgraded to other Linux kernel headers (no result).

Any tips?